# Sort column by date after it is in my environment using filter

Tags: r

My current setup
[image]

How do I filter the end_time column for data only after 12/01/2018 and then sum these data after this date?

Below is what I have already tried.

```
setwd("/Users/jackbell/Desktop")
bookings<- read.csv("bookings_data_data_analyst_test.csv", header= TRUE)
end_time<- bookings %>%select(end_time)
end_time
new_date <- filter(end_time< as.Date("12/01/2018"))
```

Answer (score 1):

We need to convert it to `Date` class.  Based on the image and the OP's code, 'end_time' seems to be the column name and there is also an object created with the same name.  In the last step, the semantic is incorrect as we need to apply `filter` on the data object.  The data object ('end_time') was not called.  Secondly, the formats for 'Date' is day/month/Year.  By default, `as.Date` returns a `Date` class if the format is `Year-month-day` (`YYYY-MM-DD`).  For all other formats, specify the `format`

```
library(tidyverse)
end_time %>% 
      filter(dmy(end_time) < dmy("12/01/2018"))
```

In the above code, we used `dmy` from `lubridate` package.  If we use `as.Date`, it would be

```
end_time %>%
      filter(as.Date(end_time, format = "%d/%m/%Y") < as.Date("2018-01-12"))
```

Comment: How do i convert to 'Date'?

Comment: @JackBell Updated the post